# Filter does no work inside forEach, in angular 6

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6, angular6

In Angular 6 I try to get each object of an array and compare it to the objects of another array. If they match, remove the object from the second array.

Based on [this](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/stop-array-foreach-and-start-using-filter-map-some-reduce-functions-298b4dabfa09),  I have the following code :

```
 existing.forEach((existingitem, existingindex, existingfeatures) => {  
  newdata2 = newdata.filter(item => (existingitem.values_.id != item.properties.id &&  existingitem.values_.cat != item.properties.cat)); 
});
```

So, if I had the existing like

```
var existing= [
  { name : "John", values_:{id:1, cat:true} }, 
  {  name : "Alice", values_:{id:2, cat:false} }  
];
```

and newdata

```
var newdata= [
  { name : "Mike", properties:{id:7, cat:true} }, 
  {  name : "Jenny", properties:{id:2, cat:false} }  
];
```

compare the `properties` of `newdata` to the `values_` of `existing` and the ones not matching end up in `newdata2` , so `newdata2` now is

```
var newdata2= [
  { name : "Mike", properties:{id:7, cat:true} }  
];
```

This may look simple, yet I get

> ERROR TypeError: newdata_1.filter is not a function

referring to the line

```
newdata2 = newdata.filter(item => (existingitem.values_.id != item.properties.id &&  existingitem.values_.cat != item.properties.cat));
```

What am I missing here? Please advice.

Thanks

EDIT

I dont set any var as `newdata_1` in my code, and all the values named `newdata` or `newdata2` are in the same block of code. I am also confused about the `newdata_1` name.  If I change the name , for example `newdatafeat`, the error becomes `ERROR TypeError: newdatafeat_1.filter is not a function` . I have no clue.

Thanks

Comment: What are your pre conditions?

Comment: @Justcode What do you mean? I have no clue. Please rephrase or explain. Thanks

Comment: Where's `newdata_1` in your code? Other than that,the code works in the console

Comment: on what bases you want output? what keys should not match?

Comment: [No error here](https://jsfiddle.net/8sxhvq3e/). I still don't understand where your `newdata_1` comes from.

Comment: @Solo check the edit on my original question. Thanks. Will also check your fiddle and let you know.

Comment: @FrancescoG. Yeah, the code looks pretty normal to me too. Check the edit in my question for more info. Thanks

Comment: Smells like compiler bug because it works with vanilla JS. You might want to open an issue.

Comment: It works in Angular also